# Prove that unity of two subspaces is a subspace if and only if one is a subspace of the other

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let V be a vector space, W and W' be linear subspaces of V. Show that:

***$W\cup W'$ is a linear subspace*** is equivalent to ***$W\subseteq W'$ or $W'\subseteq W$***

---

I have already shown that left follows from right (<-), but I can't figure out the conclusion from left to right (->).

Answer (score 1):

If we suppose that $W \not \subset W'$ and $W' \not \subset W$, then we can find a vector $v \in W$ that is not in $W'$ and a vector $v' \in W'$ that is not in $W$.

What can we say about the vector $v + v'$?

Comment: It's a combination of elements of $W\cup W'$ that is not in $W\cup W'$ itself. Ergo, $W\cup W'$ is not a linear vector space. Proof by contradiction! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Whats the argument for v+v' not being an element of the unity though?

Comment: @Joey Just think a bit about in *which* subspace it may be (the difference of 2 vectors in a subspace is still in that subspace)

Comment: You guys are awesome. This is my first time asking a question. I must say it probably won't be the last. I like your ways of helping without giving me the whole solution.